# RxJava: Read from cache until timestamp is expired

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have the following scenario: I have an object called `Foo` that my application is interested in. This `Foo` object comes from a remote service, and I would like to cache this instance locally and keep using it until a certain amount of time has passed.

So far, I've tried creating a `FooState` class that contains the instance of `Foo` along with a timestamp indicating the time the `Foo` was fetched in milliseconds:

```java
public class FooState {

    private Foo foo;
    private long timestamp;

    /* Constructor and getters */

}
```

Now, so far I've come up with this code that uses concat:

```
public Observable<Foo> foo() {
    return Observable.concat(local(), remote())
               .takeFirst(fooState -> fooState.getTimestamp() >= System.currentTimeMillis())
               .map(fooState -> fooState.getFoo())
               .defaultIfEmpty(new Foo());

}

private Observable<FooState> local() {
    return Observable.just(cache.hasFooState() ? cache.getFooState() : new FooState(null, 0));
}

private Observable<FooState> remote() {
    return api.getFoo()
              .map(foo -> new FooState(foo, System.currentTimeMillis() + ONE_DAY_MILLIS)
              .doOnNext(fooState -> {
                   cache.save(fooState);
              });
}
```

Basically, if there's a cached value, I want to use it as long as the timestamp isn't expired. If the timestamp is expired or there is no cached value, I want to fetch from the remote service and cache the result.

Is there a cleaner way to implement this use case? I'm kind of new to RxJava and I was wondering if any Rx-gurus knew of a better way to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with something similar to your approach with `concat` as it seems to be the most appropriate for this use case, but build my solution based on `Maybe` (RxJava 2) which will not emit anything from local if there is no cache or that cache entry is expired.

```
public class RxJavaUnitTestJava {
    public class Foo extends Object {
        String source = "n/a";
    }

    public class FooState {
        private Foo foo;
        private long timestamp;

        public FooState(Foo foo, long timestamp) {
            this.foo = foo;
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }
    }

    private static long EXPIRATION = 0l;
    private FooState cachedFooState = null;

    private Maybe<Foo> local() {
        return Maybe.fromCallable(() -> {
            System.out.println("checking local");

            if (cachedFooState != null && cachedFooState.timestamp + EXPIRATION > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                System.out.println("taking unexpired local");
                cachedFooState.foo.source = "local"; // mark source of this foo

                return cachedFooState.foo;
            } else {
                System.out.println("not taking local");
                return null;
            }
        });
    } 

    private Maybe<Foo> remote() {
        return Maybe.fromCallable(() -> {
            System.out.println("checking remote");

            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.source = "remote"; // mark source of this foo
            FooState fooState = new FooState(foo, System.currentTimeMillis());
            cachedFooState = fooState;

            return fooState.foo;
        });
    }

    private Observable<Foo> foo() {
        return Maybe.concat(local(), remote())
                .take(1)
                .toObservable();
    }

    @Test
    public void testNoCachedLocal() {
        cachedFooState = null;

        foo()
                .doOnNext(foo -> System.out.println("doOnNext: foo.source: " + foo.source))
                .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("onComplete"))
                .test()
                .assertValueCount(1)
                .assertComplete();
    }

    @Test
    public void testExpiredLocal() {
        cachedFooState = new FooState(new Foo(), System.currentTimeMillis());
        EXPIRATION = 0l;

        foo()
                .doOnNext(foo -> System.out.println("doOnNext: foo.source: " + foo.source))
                .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("onComplete"))
                .test()
                .assertValueCount(1)
                .assertComplete();
    }

    @Test
    public void testUnExpiredLocal() {
        cachedFooState = new FooState(new Foo(), System.currentTimeMillis());
        EXPIRATION = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30);

        foo()
                .doOnNext(foo -> System.out.println("doOnNext: foo.source: " + foo.source))
                .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("onComplete"))
                .test()
                .assertValueCount(1)
                .assertComplete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use built-in *.timestamp()* operator and *Timestamped<T>* class.

```java
    BehaviorSubject<Timestamped<Foo>> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();

    Observable<Foo> serviceCall() {
        return subject.filter(new Func1<Timestamped<Foo>, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(Timestamped<Foo> tsFoo) {
                return tsFoo.getTimestampMillis() < expiry;
            }
        }).switchIfEmpty(serviceCall().timestamp().doOnNext(new Action1<Timestamped<Foo>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Timestamped<Foo> tsFoo) {
                subject.onNext(tsFoo);
            }
        })
        .map(new Func1<Timestamped<Object>, Foo>() {
            @Override
            public Foo call(Timestamped<Object> tsFoo) {
                return tsFoo.getValue();
            }
        });
    }
```